# Object #<HTMLObjectElement> has no method 'mapFunction'\n at Object.<anonymous>

Tags: browser, flash

```
swfobject.embedSWF( .path + '/swf/TestApp.swf', id, "100%", "100%",  
      MINIMUM_REQUIRED_FLASH_PLAYER_VERSION, null, flashVars, params, null,
                function (event) {
                    if (event.success) {
                        _self.flashObject = event.ref;
                        ...
                       }
else{

    ...

}
```

later when I call

```
_self.flashObject.mapFunction(name,params) its giving below error:
```

Object # has no method 'mapFunction'\n at Object.

Please share if anybody has any inputs... its blocking me to proceed with my development...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You're using dot notation, and the object does'nt have a `mapFunction` method.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Is there any way to check object is having mapFunction or not?

Comment: _self.flashObject.hasOwnProperty('mapFunction') will help to check it I guess.